# Indonesian Currency on Angular

Tags: angularjs, localization, internationalization, currency

I want to format using currency filter in AngularJS like the following:

Rp 2.000,00

(using dot as thousand separator, and comma as decimal separator)
Currently I am using:

```
{{product.originalPrice | currency:"Rp "}}
```

The result:

Rp 2,000.00

Which is not common in our country. How to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Angular has full support of i18n and l10n.

To do what you want you have to include [angular-locale_id-id.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngLocale/angular-locale_id-id.js) and then format will be just as you need.

For your locale angular's number format is:

```
"NUMBER_FORMATS": {
  "CURRENCY_SYM": "Rp",
  "DECIMAL_SEP": ",",
  "GROUP_SEP": "."
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

`value | currency:'IDR ':'symbol':'3.0'`

or

`value | currency:'Rp':'symbol':'3.0'`

https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/angular-currency-pipe-formatting-currency-in-angular/

Comment: Please format the code as such (putting it between back-tick or on a separate row with 4 spaces in front) and try to explain why this solution works